# I need to turn my SVG into a concave dome shape. Similar as too the shape of water laying on a flat surface or a half jelly bean

Tags: shape-keys

[image]
I have these designs extruded but I would like them to be a certain shape for the blue and grey designs. I want them to be a concave dome. I am not sure how to do this could somebody guide me. More so a half of a jelly bean shape but with the design I have.

Comment: Convert the SVG to a Mesh > Use _Decimate Modifier_ set to _Planar_ on the mesh (to remove ugly geometry) - apply the modifier > Extrude the object(s) to your liking > Add loop cuts around the vertical center (equator) of each of the "beans" > Side/box select and delete all the bottom "halves" of the beans > Add a _Subdivision Surface_ Modifier.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. When I did the instructions it ended up being very jagged and not so rounded. once I added subdivision surface modifier it became jagged.

Comment: Yeah, now that I think about it, the top "caps" (which are n-gons at this point) will cause jagginess. It might help if you could post a sample of your svg, so we could test it out with your (resulting) geometry, in order to find the best method.